# Is there a way for a Constituent (or non-lobbyist) to introduce a bill in either house of the U.S. Congress?

Tags: united-states, congress, legislation, legislative-process

I am curious as to both the theoretical and practical aspects of how an individual might get a bill introduced in congress. How might one go about this?

One potential application might be for introducing a bill to get a congressperson removed from their seat. How might that work? Is this a possible route since " [Is there a procedure to recall US Senators?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/2598/is-there-a-procedure-to-recall-us-senators) " lays out how this does not appear to be possible otherwise?

Comment: Interesting question.  My gut instinct is "No" (and lobbyists can't directly introduce them either), but I look forward to seeing what answers (and documentation) this question generates.

Comment: lobbists write bills all the time, but you still need a representative to introduce the bill (sponsor). I dont believe a bill to remove a member of Congress would be effective, a proceedure already exists for removing officers (2/3rds vote). Were you interested in a costitutional amendment? (need state legislture support).

Comment: Is there any reason to think that anyone other than a member of the legislature can introduce a bill?

Comment: @DJClayworth - Not that I can think of, but I also can't think of a reason why there couldn't be a (theoretical) way to do so, either.  So the question really is: `"Why do you need to be a member to introduce a bill? Is it Constitutional? Procedural? Chamber rule?"`

Answer (score 3):

**No. In both houses, an elected representative is required to introduce a bill.**

[The House](http://kids.clerk.house.gov/grade-school/lesson.html?intID=17)

> In the U.S. House of Representatives, a bill is introduced when it is placed in the hopper—a special box on the side of the clerk’s desk. **Only Representatives can introduce bills in the U.S. House of Representatives**.

[The Senate](http://www.senate.gov/reference/resources/pdf/legprocessflowchart.pdf) flowchart:

> Bill is introduced by Senator

For more information on the process, you might want to research [How a Bill Becomes a Law](https://kids.usa.gov/teens-home/goverment/how-a-bill-becomes-a-law/index.shtml)

Comment: That helps a lot, but during the process, after the bill goes to committee, what effect can citizens have on a bill, to help it succeed? Do the public hearings really matter?

In the case of say a House resolution to suspend a member, since that only affects that chamber, wouldn't it be considered a simple resolution, needing only the House to vote on it? (Which leaves the problem of convincing your congressperson to introduce the resolution, which might be considered in _poor form_ by their peers...)

Comment: To nitpick, according to the Senate rules the Vice President could introduce a bill from the President, which would not involve a member of Congress.